# Using Batch File to Open Another Cmd Prompt and Run Cmd in that Cmd Prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I have another bat file that I'm running, and once in the command prompt that bat file creates, I want to run another command in that window.

Here's what I have so far:

```
call C:\Batch\MyBatFile.bat (this creates the new command prompt that I want to use)
C:\Program\MyProgram.exe
```

However, the second line is being run in the original window, instead of the new command prompt.  I tried using `start C:\Program\MyProgram.exe`, but that just ran in a 3rd new window instead.

If it's relevant, the first line is just setting a few environment variables that I need access to and `MyProgram` is a visual studio 2010 project.  Technically, I might be able to modify that bat to run the command, but I'd rather avoid that solution as that bat file isn't owned by me (and thus whenever it's updated I'd have to update mine as well).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `MyProgram` should be included within `MyBatFile` in order for it to run in the created command prompt. I do not think you can "talk" to it and make it do more.

Comment: That entirely depends on what the batch file does.  It could take a parameter like `cmd /k`.

Comment: It the batch file does not accept parameters (we will never know ;)), then either way, you would have to modify the batch file.

Comment: I was hoping to "talk" to it to make it do more.  Sounds like that's not an option though and that I'll have to modify it.

Comment: What exactly is `MyBatFile.bat` doing? And can you just include those environment variables in your script?

Comment: My knowledge of batch files is pretty limited, but as far as I can tell it's creating several dozen environment variables and opening a new command prompt with those variables set.

I could certainly include those environment variables in my script.  But then I've added another place that needs to be maintained whenever those variables are modified.

Comment: @JuniorIncanter: do you know why that bat file is opening a new command prompt after setting the variables? Using `CALL` sources the variables into the local context so it probably isn't needed (i.e. the opening of the new prompt). But for that same reason, you probably already have those variables set as you are wanting by the time MyProgram.exe is executed. Is MyProgram.exe working correctly? If so, it is just a minor annoyance that there is another command prompt open, but I don't think you need to use it.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what that script is doing.  When I run the .exe by itself, it throws an error saying one of the environment variables is null or empty (that I know MyBatFile.bat sets).  My understanding was that those environment variables are only set for the command prompt they run in.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @JuniorIncanter: I just posted an answer to hopefully be clearer about the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to inject your `program.exe` into `cmd` created by `batfile.bat` by redirecting it's input stream and then sending it a command, eg. `echo C:\Program\MyProgram.exe | C:\Batch\MyBatFile.bat`. This assumes that batch really just sets bunch of variables and does not use commands which reset/consume input stream.

Please note that if redirected/piped this way new command window **will not stay open** It will *maybe :-)* just execute your command and then close/exit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CMD script to run both of the commands that you have shown in the question. Maybe call it `RunMyProgram.cmd`. The contents are just the two lines that you have:

```
REM Source the environment variables.
REM Any new command prompt window that is opened can be ignored
CALL C:\Batch\MyBatFile.bat

C:\Program\MyProgram.exe
```

If what you have stated in the comments to your question is accurate regarding `MyBatFile.bat` setting up the environment variables and then starting a new window, then you should be able to make use of those environment variables after `MyBatFile.bat` exits.

If running `RunMyProgram.cmd` from a command prompt still has `MyProgram.exe` giving the error when the environment variable is not set, or if `MyProgram.exe` doesn't even start to run until you close the new window that popped up, then we need to see the exact commands that `MyBatFile.bat` is executing.